# What is the difference between mauling and transaction malleability?

Tags: transactions, segregated-witness

http://stevengoldfeder.com/papers/ZKCSP.pdf notes:

> The protocol presented in [5] is vulnerable to the so-called mauling problem, where an adversary
>   which knows the hash identifier T of a transaction is able to come up with a hash identifier T
>   0
>   that
>   is semantically equivalent to T (i.e. spends the same transaction, has the same value, and the
>   same inputs and outputs). As the authors of [5] point out, there are many Bitcoin software clients
>   that cannot handle transactions appearing in the ledger with an hash identifier which is different
>   from the original one (namely, the one with which they were posted) [3]. This effectively makes
>   the transaction unredeemable, causing problems when creating Bitcoin contracts [2,3]. While the
>   authors acknowledge the mauling problem, their scheme only addresses mauling due to malleability
>   in ECDSA signatures, but does not address mauling due to changing the script.

The reference [5] cited is [Efficient Zero-Knowledge Contingent Payments in
Cryptocurrencies Without Scripts](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/451.pdf)

This sounds a lot like transaction malleability. What is the difference?

If it is not the same, is mauling fixed by Segregated Witness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They define what they mean by mauling in the referenced paper:

> As described in Section 2, the Bitcoin transactions are identified by their hashes, more precisely: TXid(T) = H(T) (where H is the SHA256 hash function). This can sometimes be a problem, since it turns out that often the adversary that knows T can compute T' that is semantically equivalent to T (i.e.: spends the same transaction, has the same value, and the same inputs and outputs), but is syntactically different from T. This is called mauling the transaction T. In a moment we will explain how mauling can be done, but let us first say what are the consequences of this attack. The problem comes from the fact that in such a case TXid(T) != TXid(T'). Note that this does not imply that the adversary can steal money (as the output of T is the same as the output of T'). Still, it is undesirable in many situations.

This is the same thing as transaction malleability.

Would segregated witness solve this? I believe so. If every input is a segwit spend, that solves every kind of transaction malleability, except when the attacker has a copy of every private key that signed the transaction.